# How to filter out the background in an RGB image(Matlab)?

Tags: image, matlab, background, rgb, pixel

I'd like to know how i can automatically filter out background pixels,basically turning them back so i have only the main object in RGB using matlab,i did try many methods,the most successful was region growing but i can't have human intervention so it was eliminated.

Comment: A sample image, the actual methods you tried (and how they did not work for you), and the desired output would help to narrow down the possible answers. Otherwise this question is impossibly broad.

Comment: I did try providing a seed basically giving samples of the pixel colors i want as well as Edge based methods,took the grayscale of each of the layers then tried to blur but wasn't satisfied with my results,and can't post a picture not enough reputation points.

Comment: You can still post an image online (somewhere like imgur) and add the link to your question. Somebody will likely be along to edit the picture itself into the post for you.